# Angular - 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the `TypeIdentifierService` class that extends another class,
in the `TypeIdentifierService` class i inject the `ConfigService` and i use this service in the super method, but it shows me this error

> 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a
>   derived class.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService<T> {

    constructor(
        @Inject('API_BASE_URL') protected url: string,
        protected httpClient: HttpClient,
        protected responseHandler: HttpResponseHandler
    ) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class TypeIdentifierService extends DataService<Dictionary> {

    constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, responseHandler: HttpResponseHandler, private config: ConfigService) {
        super(`${this.config.getSettings('environment.serviceBaseUrl.sp')}/typeIdentifiers`, httpClient, responseHandler);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello. You don't have access on "this" in a super constructor:

 `super(`${**this**.config.getSettings('environment.serviceBaseUrl.sp')}/typeIdentifiers`, httpClient, responseHandler);`